# Enabling Hyper-V on Windows 10 not working, error 14081, HP Compaq Elite 8300

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I'm trying to enable Hyper-V on my Windows 10 and tried several articles and they all point me to the same place to enable Hyper-V, either with PowerShell/CMD or through the Control Panel.

All ways to enable Hyper-V are failing and I can't figure out why.
System information:

- Windows 10 Pro
- HP Compaq Elite 8300
- Virtualization Technology (VTx) enabled in BIOS
- Intel Core i7 3770
- BIOS version 3.04, 7-nov-2016 (newest as far as I can see)

So I took these steps (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v):

1. Start CMD as Administrator
2. Then I type: ***DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V***

Result:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.14393.0

Image Version: 10.0.14393.0

Enabling feature(s)
[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 14081

The referenced assembly could not be found.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

You can find the dism log here: https://pastebin.com/PTpvh3KW

I see some errors around 9:03:20 but I doesn't make any sense to me.
After a lot of Googling and no answer found, I will give Superuser a chance.

Hopefully someone can help me and tell me what's going on :(
If you guys need me to provide more information, please let me know

PS.: I already tried dism scanhealth, and no corruptions where found (based on the output of dism itself)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.14393.0

Image Version: 10.0.14393.0

[==========================100.0%==========================] No component store corruption detected.
The operation completed successfully.
```

You can find the dism scanhealth log here: https://pastebin.com/9rRQW7vW

Comment: Bit off the wall, but have you ensure the BIOS is up to date?

Comment: Good point, I have version v2.51 (15-jun-12) and on the HP website I see newer versions 2.99(19-okt-2015) & v3.04 (7-nov-2016). I will try to update the BIOS and see if that helps

Comment: I updated my bios to v2.99 and tried to enable Hyper-V, didn't work. Then I updated to 3.04 and still I get the same error. So maybe there is something else I'm missing/not seeing?

Comment: Can you type `systeminfo` into a Command prompt and paste up the "Hyper-V Requirements" output. There are four necessary requirements according to Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/reference/hyper-v-requirements

Comment: Sure, you can see the result here: https://pastebin.com/bdbJ61Jt  I already checked this, before asking, all Hyper-V options state "Yes"

Comment: Do you have your Windows 10 Pro ISO (or access to one)? I wonder if you may need to do `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:O:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess` where your source is your DVD... I see you'v edone "scanhealth" but you may need to go one step further. I would recommend using the ISO/WIM as source rather than the built-in ESD because then it's guaranteed clean

Comment: I downloaded Windows from the MS website and made a USB bootable (with the software MS recommends). But I don't see a install.wim on the USB only in G(USB):\sources\install.esd. Not sure if this works, but I tried with /Source:esd:G:\sources\install.esd:1 and I get 'The restore operation completed succesfully'. Unfortunately that didn't fix the Hyper-V DISM issue

Comment: integerate the latest update rollup MSU into the install.wim and point to it with source parameter **DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V /source:wim:D:\install.wim:1**

Comment: Can you give me a link that explains how I can do that? The rollup of MSU into install.wim?

Comment: next time use google, it only takes 5s to find [several guides](https://4sysops.com/archives/use-dism-to-slipstream-updates/). [Last rollup can be found here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4000825/windows-10-windows-server-2016-update-history)

Comment: @Kinnectus -

Hyper-V Requirements:
VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
Second Level Address Translation: Yes
Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes